# Storing cut up potatoes (chips/fries)

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, potatoes

I have fallen into a slump at the minute where i just don't feel like preparing food when i get home from work, and i would prefer to cut up a larger batch of potatoes in one go and store them in the fridge/freezer in the correct portion sizes, so when i get home i can just throw them into the oven.

The problem i have had with this up to now is, if i put them into the freezer and then try to cook them, the defrosting process turns them to mush. If i put them in the fridge, they have gone off by morning.

Is there a better way to store potatoes that have been cut up?

Comment: [They can be frozen](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75055/how-to-time-the-blanching-of-potatoes-for-freezing), maybe you should experiment with different potato variaties.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43820/preserving-whole-potatoes

Comment: How many days in advance/how many portions. Please be specific, [edit] your question? If one day, then [here is your answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/26173/preserve-cut-potatoes). **Hint**: As you can see I'm [searching this site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+potatoes) - it does not look like you did

Comment: @JanDoggen The question about preserving whole potatoes is not relevant to this question. The next, about how to time the blanching of potatoes before freezing, may be slightly related but does not really address this question. And I wouldn't have expected the OP to look at either of those questions based on their title.

Answer (score 7):

You can store your cut potatoes in the fridge. Place them in container(s) and cover them completely with plain, unsalted water. They should be fine for at least 2 or 3 days.

I don't know that it's necessary, but I usually drain and rinse them before use.

Alternatively, as you are cooking them in the oven, you could cook a large batch and then store your preferred portion sizes in the fridge or freezer, depending on how long you plan to keep them before use.

Comment: WARNING: In case you ever want to deep fry these, make sure you drain them *well* - being sloppy with extra water can be enough to cause an overboil!

Comment: @rackandboneman Good point. I didn't address that as the OP specifically says he wants to 'just throw them in the oven'.

Comment: I was a chef at a bar, and this is exactly what I did for my shoestring fries. I'd cut them by the bucket, cover them with plain water, and dry them with a salad spinner before I frying them up. It also takes off some of the starch off, which can make them stay blonde a little longer while cooking through. I like dark fries, but most people seem to prefer them a little more McDonaldsesque. It also works great with homemade crisps/'potato chips'

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, supermarket bought frozen french fries are boiled briefly before being frozen. This steps takes out some of the starch while partially cooking them. Then when you fry them, they are soft from the inside and crispy outside.
To try this, boil water and salt, add cut fries and boil for 2 minutes. Move out to an ice bath to stop the cooking and dry them completely before freezing.

You can also partially cook them by frying them for 5-6 minutes in 325°F (163°C) oil. Then remove and let cool completely. Pat dry and freeze.

In both methods, make sure you fry on high heat, 375 to 400°F (196 to 204°C).

Comment: Supermarket frozen french fries often (not always) are not actually just cut up potatoes, especially the oven optimized variety...

Comment: Your answer contains some good information, but the OP didn't ask about prepping the potatoes for frying at a later time. Per the question, they would be cooked in the oven.

Comment: http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-freeze-your-own-french-fries-235216 does this and recommends tossing in oil and freezing in a single layer on a baking sheet before moving to a freezer bag. This does make for more work, but otherwise I think you'd end up with a big frozen clump of potatoes in your freezer.

Answer (score 1):

If youre going to keep them lven baked rather than frying, make sure you rinse your potatoes after cutting them into fries... Cold water will do fine. Once the water runs clear, that means most of the starch is off. Then you can let them sit in water in a container completely covered for 2 days for sure. If you want to fry them, you rinse them until the water runs clear, then you blanch your fries in oil at 180F for 4 minutes and let them sit out for a few hours until they have cooled off.then you can put them in containers completely sealed and do not put them back in water if you had blanched them. This will last for 2 days as well.enjoy :)